# About Rx's CombineLatest and default initial values

Tags: .net, f#, system.reactive

Given 2 types `A` and `B` with default values `d(A)` & `d(B)`.
And 2 Subjects:

```
let sa = new Subject<A>()
let sb = new Subject<B>()
```

And a function `f` of type `A -> B -> C`

I created this observable:

```
let o = Observable.CombineLatest(sa, sb, f)
```

However, I need `o` to produce an initial value based on the `d(A)` & `d(B)`. The docs say that CombineLatest will only produce its first output once both subjects have produce their first output.

I have 2 approaches, but I don't know which will work/ which is the best or if I'm missing some operator that already does what I need.

The first approach I came up is to manually call `OnNext` to `sa` and `sb` with the default values after the relevant subscriptions to `o` have been made.

My second approach is to use `BehaviorSubject`s instead of plain `Subject`s, create them with the initial values and hope that CombineLatest will use that for its first output.

Thanks for reading.

**Addendum**
I've confirmed that the 2nd approach works, but still I don't know if introducing a `BehaviorSubject` instead of a plain `Subject` is the best for this case.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How about using `StartWith`?

```cs
public static Observable<T> StartWithDefault(this Observable<T> observable) {
    return observable.StartWith(default(T));
}
```

Then:

```
sa.StartWithDefault().CombineLatest(sb.StartWithDefault(), f)
```

Comment: There is actually a `.StartWith` operation especially for this case.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Even better.

Comment: Thx. How hard would it have been to mention that here when talking about exactly this problem! https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html

Comment: Just for 'fun' here's the source for the `StartWith` operator : 
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/37d9ea9a8665d0c4b6593da4c237e037e98f66b5/src/internal/operators/startWith.ts

Comment: The current docs suggest this has to done inside a `.pipe()` like this `observable.pipe(startWith(''));`